# Inverse Limit of Complexs and Homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, limits-colimits, derived-functors, derived-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category and denote by $D(\mathcal{A})$ its derived category. Let $K_n\in D(\mathcal{A})$ be an inverse system of complexes in $\mathcal{A}$ viewed as elements of the derived category. We have a natural map
$$ \lim K_n\rightarrow K_n$$
and thus
$$H_m(\lim K_n)\rightarrow \lim H_m(K_n).$$
Since $\lim$ is in general not an exact functor, this won't be an isomorphism. Do we know more about this map, for instance is surjective in general? The only case I can deal with is the short exact sequence of complexes
$$0\rightarrow A^\bullet \rightarrow B^\bullet \rightarrow C^\bullet\rightarrow 0$$
because that yields a long exact sequence
$$\ldots\rightarrow H_m(\lim B^\bullet \rightarrow C^\bullet\leftarrow 0)\rightarrow H_m(B^\bullet)\rightarrow H_m(C^\bullet)\rightarrow \ldots$$
and thus we have a surjection
$$H_m(\lim B^\bullet \rightarrow C^\bullet\leftarrow 0)\rightarrow \ker \left( H_m(B^\bullet)\rightarrow H_m(C^\bullet) \right)\cong \lim \left( H_m(B^\bullet)\rightarrow H_m(C^\bullet) \leftarrow H_m(0) \right) .$$
However, I don't know how to generalize this.

Comment: I believe this is related to homotopy limits

Comment: @AviSteiner Could you elaborate?

Comment: This is related to "Milnor exact sequences": see "For chain homology" in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lim%5E1+and+Milnor+sequences. At least if the chain complex satisfies some sort of mild finiteness condition (the Mittag-Leffler condition), the map you give is a surjection, and its kernel can be identified.